# 'float' object has no attribute 'round'

Tags: python, keras

I have a code was shown below:

```
history['test_acc'].append(results.history['val_dense_5_accuracy'][0])
```

then I want to print like below:

```
 print('Epoch: '+str(epoch)+'/'+str(epochs-1), 'Learning rate:', 
      'Test_acc:', history['test_acc'][-1].round(4),
      'Test_loss:', history['test_loss'][-1].round(4))`
```

but in this this line:

```
'Test_acc:', history['test_acc'][-1].round(4)
```

i have this error: 'float' object has no attribute 'round'
what's the problem?

Answer (score 37):

The problem is that [`round` is a built-in top level function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round), not a method on `float`s. Change:

```
history['test_acc'][-1].round(4)
```

to:

```
round(history['test_acc'][-1], 4)
```

with a similar change to the `test_loss` expression.